# Remove dotted leaders from lists of tables/figures in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have set up a format for my table of contents in which the page number follows the section name rather than being separated by a dotted leader. But my lists of tables, figures, and so on still have the dotted leader.

How do I format the lists the same way as the table of contents?

Here is the setup for the TOC within a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Put TOC page numbers after title, not on right margin
% No dotted leaders
% Set number left-aligned in a box starting 1 em to the right of title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{%
    \cftchapterformatpnumhook{#1}%
    \nolinebreak[4]\hspace*{1em}\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftchapterpagefont #1}\hfill}%
}

\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{%
    \cftsectionformatpnumhook{#1}%
    \nolinebreak[4]\hspace*{1em}\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftsectionpagefont #1}\hfill}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{table}
\framebox{TABLE}
\caption{Table}
\label{table1}
\end{table}

\section{Section}

\begin{figure}
\framebox{FIGURE}
\caption{Figure}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{table}
\framebox{TABLE}
\caption{Table}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\section{Section}

\begin{figure}
\framebox{FIGURE}
\caption{Figure}
\label{figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hope I haven't misunderstood your question...

Comment: @karlkoeller Nope, you nailed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add also

```
\renewcommand{\cfttableleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttableafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Put TOC page numbers after title, not on right margin
% No dotted leaders
% Set number left-aligned in a box starting 1 em to the right of title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{%
    \cftchapterformatpnumhook{#1}%
    \nolinebreak[4]\hspace*{1em}\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftchapterpagefont #1}\hfill}%
}

\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{%
    \cftsectionformatpnumhook{#1}%
    \nolinebreak[4]\hspace*{1em}\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftsectionpagefont #1}\hfill}%
}
\renewcommand{\cfttableleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttableafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{table}
\framebox{TABLE}
\caption{Table}
\label{table1}
\end{table}

\section{Section}

\begin{figure}
\framebox{FIGURE}
\caption{Figure}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{table}
\framebox{TABLE}
\caption{Table}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\section{Section}

\begin{figure}
\framebox{FIGURE}
\caption{Figure}
\label{figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Now I see this is one of those `cftK` things in the manual where you have to substitute other things for `K`. For others who like me have defined custom lists using `\newfloat`, the value for `K` here is the first argument of `\newfloat`. E.g., for a list of examples made by `\newfloat[chapter]{example}{loe}{\examplename}` then you need `\renewcommand{\cftexampleleader}{}`.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Happy to help. And yes, you're right about the meaning of `K` ;-)