# Does someone know how to remove dot leader in list of tables and list of figures?

Tags: tables

```
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\begin{center} 
            \vspace{-0.24in}
        \normalsize \textbf{\protect\vspace{-0.2in}LIST OF FIGURES}     
        \addtocontents{lof}{\hspace{0.3cm}\textbf{Figure}}
        \addtocontents{lof}{\hspace{12.4cm}\textbf{Page}\par}       
    \end{center}}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\hspace{-2.4cm}\protect\vspace{0cm}\numberline{}\textmd{LIST OF FIGURES}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\begin{center} 
            \vspace{-0.24in}
        \normalsize \textbf{\protect\vspace{-0.2in}LIST OF TABLES}
    \addtocontents{lot}{\textbf{Table}}
    \addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\end{center}}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\hspace{-2.4cm}\protect\vspace{0.5cm}\numberline{}\textmd{LIST OF TABLES}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with a complete minimal working example, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and shows the issue. It often helps to supplement this by a screen shot illustrating the problem and/or desired outcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235965/remove-dotted-leaders-from-lists-of-tables-figures-in-memoir

Answer (score 1):

By using the `tocloft` package along these lines:

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftnodots} % no dots in list of figures
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{\cftnodots} % no dots in list of tables
...
```

Read the `tocloft` documentation (`> texdoc tocloft`) for more information.